# Task Consumer microservice architecture flow

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, asp.net-core-3.1, api-design

[image]I'm trying to re-building Task Consumer microservice which has below task

- Consume rabbitMQ
- Call to API as per need and add or update database
- Insert initial set up data which will be used by API/UI independently.

**I'm not sure whether initial set up data needs to be in Taskconsumer service or I should move it to API . API has access to DB by EFramework code first approach. So might needs to just move my DML/DDL queries to Data access layer which can be triggered by API ? .**

what Initial set up data do

1. creation of indexes on the same table which are used by API
2. Insert Enums, Types etc which is neccessary to run the App
   etc.

Any suggestion/comments are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most modern stacks, you don't want more than one code base coupled to a given database.  It makes keeping things synchronized complicated.  So yes, if you are going to be talking to the database through your API (call it a service, it will be easier to find examples), then your task consumer should be invoking that API to add/change things.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I thought so. Thanks for commenting. Keep coding....:)